# Include the EmployeeID as claims in tokens in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, access-token

I need to add the employeeid as claim notification in token, I used the tutorial of this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#include-the-employeeid-and-tenantcountry-as-claims-in-tokens

I did all steps, but my token is not returning the employeeid:

[image]

I did this configuration with graph api, where I create the policy and bind it with the service principal:

If I check this configuration, it seems to be correct:

I have followed all the steps correctly, and I can't include the employeeid in the token, what is happening? thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you specified JwtClaimType twice in your policy. Also in your token it looks like "name" might be your employee ID? Remove the second JwtClaimType from your policy that specifies "name" and try again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have updated the post with the new screenshots after making the change you told me, and employeeid still does not appear in the token.

Comment: @DanielVegaRuiz I think that `ID` should be `ExtensionID`. Quote Microsoft docs: "When you define a claims mapping policy for a directory extension attribute, use the ExtensionID property instead of the ID property within the body of the ClaimsSchema array, as shown in the example above."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an access token you are requesting, you could check two things:1.The claims mapping policy should be attached to the resource (api) service principal/application id for which you are requesting the access token 2. You need to update the application manifest as mentioned towards the end of the document you shared.

Comment: Yes, I attached the claimsmappingpolicy with the service principal, and I changed in the manifest the value of  "acceptMappedClaims": true, but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment getting the employeeid successfully***

[image]

Make sure you have choose your ***Application object ID***

[image]

For your Reference :

https://s4erka.wordpress.com/2020/08/06/azuread-claim-mapping-policy/

Comment: Application object ID?? I get this value from object id of my app in enterprise applications, because if I use the object ID of my application in app registration , the response is that the resource does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Comment: What api permission have you configured in your application for your example??

Comment: Thanks, I did it,  but still not working, the employeeid is not displayed in the token